# In xsl list a CDs tracks with added total time for each track

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<cd>
<track>
    <track_no>
        1
    </track_no>
    <title>
        Sometitle
    </title>
    <duration_music>
        213
    </duration_music>
    <duration_pause>
        8
    </duration_pause>
</track>
<track>
    <track_no>
        2
    </track_no>
    <title>
        Someothertitle
    </title>
    <duration_music>
        223
    </duration_music>
    <duration_pause>
        6
    </duration_pause>
</track>
<track>
    <track_no>
        3
    </track_no>
    <title>
        Someother3title
    </title>
    <duration_music>
        157
    </duration_music>
    <duration_pause>
        12
    </duration_pause>
</track>
<track>
    ..
    ..
</track>
```

Durations above are in seconds.
I want to do a "backside-label" printing all titles in sequence, but also showing the total start and end time, including pauses, counting from the beginning, like:

```
<cd>
<BackSide>
Start       End         Duration    Pause       Tr_no   Title
00:00:00    00:03:33    00:03:33    00:00:08    1       Sometitle
00:03:41    00:07:24    00:03:43    00:00:06    2       Someothertitle
00:07:30    00:10:07    00:02:37    00:00:12    3       Someother3title
..
..

</BackSide>
```

Timing above are HH:MM:SS (hours:minutes:seconds)
I can easily do the listing with track numbers, titles and durations (and a total time if needed), but the trick is how to do the calculations of start-and end times for each track, by adding music duration and pauses "as we go" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires a formatting template for the times, and two selectors for the sum of preceding times for track start and end times:

**Stylesheet:**

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="'&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;&#xa;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>CD Times</title>
        <style type="text/css">
          table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Arial', sans-serif;
          }
          th, td {
            border: 1px solid silver;
          }
          th {
            text-align: left;
          }
          th, td {
            padding: 5px;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="cd"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cd">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Start</th>
          <th>End</th>
          <th>Duration</th>
          <th>Pause</th>
          <th>Tr_no</th>
          <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="track"/>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="track">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:call-template name="format_seconds">
          <xsl:with-param name="time" select="sum(preceding-sibling::track/duration_pause | preceding-sibling::track/duration_music)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:call-template name="format_seconds">
          <xsl:with-param name="time" select="sum(preceding-sibling::track/duration_pause | preceding-sibling::track/duration_music) + duration_music"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:call-template name="format_seconds">
          <xsl:with-param name="time" select="duration_music"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:call-template name="format_seconds">
          <xsl:with-param name="time" select="duration_pause"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(track_no)"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(title)"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="format_seconds">
    <xsl:param name="time"/>
    <xsl:variable name="hours" select="floor($time div 3600)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="floor(($time - $hours * 3600) div 60)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="seconds" select="$time - ($hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($hours, '00:')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($minutes, '00:')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($seconds, '00')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

[image: HTML Table CD-Times]

Comment: You should store the result of the sum() in a variable, instead of calling it repeatedly.

Comment: I don't see any issue, an average CD has 20 tracks. But anyway, can you show how to do that in XSLT, since variables can't be re-declared?

Comment: **1.** It's a matter of good practice (+ every CPU cycle you save reduces global warming...) **2.** There's no need to re-declare the variable; just declare it once, within the template matching `track`.

Comment: Great thanks, that works fine for me. Didn't need the html-part, but I can easily strip that..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the source XML document lists the tracks in the correct order, you can calculate the starting point of each track by:

```
sum(preceding-sibling::track/duration_music) + sum(preceding-sibling::track/duration_pause)
```